# Copy PictureBox by context

Tags: vb.net, copy, picturebox

I have a picturebox that is being controlled by a third party app (a finger print scan). I wish to copy this picture to a picturebox in a different form. The problem is that the picturebox.image appears to be empty at least in debug, and therefore copies nothing when doing picurebox1.image = picturebox2.image.

The code that assigns the third party control is:

```
m_SecuBSP.CaptureWindowOption.FingerWindow = picturebox1.Handle.ToInt32()
```

Later on in the code I try:

```
picturebox1.image = picturebox2.image
```

no error, but no image either.

I am sure it has to do something like copying by graphic context. But how do you do that?

Comment: The `PictureBox` uses BackGroundImage, Image, and ImageLocation do you know which is being set by the control? Check them while debugging.

Comment: In debug everything is empty: image = nothing, backgroundimage=nothing, imagelocation= nothing. And of course I can see an image being displayed in the form!

Comment: ergo your results. Do you have any documentation for this control or does the vendor have support? That would be the best way from here.

Comment: no support that is why I was asking here. The control has the information, as the image is displayed. So somebody could know a different approach.